# Mysql - Unique index or columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a Mysql-table with some data. All the data is ordered by 3 column entries and all queries rely on these columns, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `column1`=0 AND `column2`=0 AND `column3`=0
```

should only return on result. My problem are possible duplicates that could occur when new data is inserted and the new data got the same values as other data in the table, so the query above would return two results. My code would use the first result, so new data could overwrite already existing data if inserted false. I thought of preventing this by uniting column1, column2 and column3 in on column4 that is of type BIGINT (if a bigger index is needed i can change to varbinary or something else instead) and change my request queries that way, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `column1`=0 AND `column2`=1 AND `column3`=2
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `column4`=((0 << 16) | (1 << 8) | 2)
//Note: column1, column2 and column3 are all TINYINTs, therefore the << 8 and << 16
```

and so on. But this makes queries less readable and my code less understandable. Are there any ideas how i can let my table how it is (with its 3 columns) and prevent data duplicates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create unique index on these 3 columns and use INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. Then it will just update if it finds previously saved record with the same 3 column data.

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX columnsetindex ON mytable(column1, column2, column3)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what your want but here its not possible to add duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `colA` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `colB` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `colC` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `colABC_UNIQUE` (`colA` ASC, `colB` ASC, `colC` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: do you think an index is also suitable for many data entries?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: If i have many entries that way and they all store a small amount of the whole data, then the index data must be also big, or do i miss something?

Comment: I do not understand your meanings, what the create SQL does is creating a table where the combination `colA`, `colB` and `colC` are unique.

So

    INSERT INTO table(id, colA, colB, colC)
    VALUES
    (1, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
    (2, 'a', 'b', 'c');

Will not be possible.

Comment: I completely understand that your solution is what i looked for. I just thought that every created index needs memory on the hard drive so i was asking if the memory needed could be a large amount.